# Foreach loop using Regex to find XML pattern

Tags: c#, excel, foreach, openxml, openxml-sdk

I've created a regex pattern which finds all `#REF` in my excel file. I've created a `foreach` loop to return all the `#REF` and siplay them in the console along with a count of them. This works fine. However I then created a `foreach` loop to remove all the `#REF` references but it only removes one each time I run the project. I've debugged this and after Regex finds the match once in the if statement the next time it enters into the foreach it skips the if statement as if it can't find another match. I'm not sure why this is

My code is as fallows

Code to return all the #ref values

```
        using (var spreadsheet = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument.Open(@"C:\Users\Craig\Desktop\newTest.xlsx", true))
        {

            var workbook = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart;
            Workbook w = new Workbook();
            var names = workbook.Workbook.DefinedNames;
            var work = workbook.Workbook;






            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"#REF");

            int count = result.InactiveNamedRangeCount = names.Count(n => regex.IsMatch(n.InnerText));
            Console.WriteLine(count);
            foreach (var name in names)
            {
                if (regex.IsMatch(name.InnerText))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(name.InnerText);
                }
            }
```

Code to delete each `#REF` value

```
            foreach (var name in names)
            {

                if (regex.IsMatch(name.InnerText))
                {
                    name.Remove();
                    work.Save();

                }
            }


            Console.WriteLine(count);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Where is the xml here ?

Comment: Because I'm getting the #REF from within an excel file which is essentially a zipped folder of xml documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem was I needed to add a `ToList` to my names variable.

```
foreach (var name in names.ToList())
            {

                if (regex.IsMatch(name.InnerText))
                {
                    name.Remove();
                    work.Save();

                }
            }
```